# Old OCX plugin does not run on Windows 2016

Tags: vb6, navision

We have an old OCX component written in VB6 that should be running on a Windows 2016 server that is giving some strange behaviors. 
The component runs on a windows 2008 R2 and and windows 2003 environment.

One of the things we noticed is.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
```

Causes an exception, when we change the code to

```
 Dim fso As FileSystemObject
 Set fso = New FileSystemObject
```

the exception is gone.

the form we are starting is started from a user control with the following code

```
Public Function Initialize(Optional ByVal pstrMapIni As String, Optional ByVal lGuiAllowed As Boolean = True)
  GUIALLOWED = lGuiAllowed
  If right(pstrMapIni, 1) <> "\" Then
    pstrMapIni = pstrMapIni + "\"
  End If
  pstrMapIni = pstrMapIni + "map.ini"
  frmMain.SetMapIni (pstrMapIni)
  Load frmMain
End Function
```

the Load frmMain fails with a null ref exception

if someone has any idea of what direction we need to search... we are out of them.

Comment: Just guessing, a note aside: won't the function invocation `frmMail.SetMapIni()` already cause the loading of frmMain...? Maybe You can try to revisit these two lines of code to somewhat more clear.

Comment: Can you be clear on what exactly the errors you're seeing are? "null ref" isn't VB6 terminology. Also, can you explain what [tag:dynamics-nav] has to do with this?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr.: old versions of Dynamics-Nav (former Navision) had implemented a COM interface, maybe this question refers to a VB component for Navision. Anyway, IMHO this question is missing some relevant pieces of code, for example - just guessing for the second time - I can't understand why the GUIAllowed parameter isn't used here, if this component is installed server-side.

Comment: Please add details of the specific error you are receiving.

Comment: Are You aware that `GUIALLOWED` is a read-only property? You can check if this component is running on the Application Server but You can't set this property.